# Add view in MoviePlayer Full screen iOS 6

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6.1, keywindow

I want to add a custom view (Customize bar) in `mpmovieplayercontroller` in full screen. I tried below code:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.viewMediaControls];
```

Its working fine in iOS 5 but its not working in iOS 6. So please can any one suggest me idea for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check answer given in below link. This may be duplicate of that question.
[Adding views to MPMoviePlayerController view after touching fullscreen button in control style MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844225/adding-views-to-mpmovieplayercontroller-view-after-touching-fullscreen-button-in)